# Physics object doesn't bounce correctly at low speed in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am running into a problem where when a physics enabled ball is going slowly it doesn't bounce off objects correctly. I have made a video to illustrate the problem

https://youtu.be/9T1hkir7sCo

Basically, the ball should run into the stationary ball and the stationary one should bounce off. This works when the speed is fast enough, but below a threshold they both just start moving together, which looks weird.

Whats going with this, and how can I make it react properly?

Experiment details (same for both objects):

RigidBody

- Mass: 1
- Drag: 0
- Angular Drag: 0
- Use gravity: false

Physics material:

- Dynamic friction: 0
- Static friction: 0
- Bounciness: 1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unity's default 
[`Bounce Threshold`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicsManager.html) for recognizing bounces is a velocity `> 2`

> Set a velocity value. If two colliding objects have a relative velocity below this value, they do not bounce off each other. This value also reduces jitter, so it is not recommended to set it to a very low value.

---

You can change this `Bounce Threshold` in the `PhysicsManager` (<kbd>Edit</kbd>-><kbd>Project Settings</kbd>-><kbd>Physics</kbd>):

[image]

or via script on runtime (see [Physics.bounceThreshold](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics-bounceThreshold.html))

```
Physics.bounceThreshold = 1;
```

---

Make it as small as you need it ... but note

> This value also reduces jitter, so it is not recommended to set it to a very low value.

[image]

Comment: Very well documented answer. Thank you for your effort. This is exactly what i needed